# Нажата ли кнопка мыши?

Tags: c++, qt

Как в любой промежуток времени определить нажата ли кнопка мыши, без использования событий и `QApplication::mouseButtons()`?

Comment: А повесить лисенер на нажатие кнопки, который ставит булевую переменную в true, если кнопка нажата, и в false - если отжата, а потом просто проверять это переменную в любой момент времени, нельзя так?

Comment: Откуда такие строгие требования?

Comment: Важно именно Qt-решение или подойдёт решение для конкретной платформы? Если да, то укажите платформу.

Comment: нужно Qt-решение, строгие требования требует логика програмы.

Comment: как поставить lisener на нажатия кнопки? покажите пример кода.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, а чем это будет отличаться от `QApplication::mouseButtons()`? Насколько я понимаю, логика там та же

Comment: @ixSci да в принципе ничем, логика та же самая

Comment: @Тарас, думаю, что через QT без событий и `QApplication` это невозможно.

Comment: Написать ассемблерную вставку?

Comment: @HermannZheboldov ассемблерную Qt-вставку? :)

Comment: @alexolut а в чем, собственно, проблема? Жаль в комментариях пример нельзя привести.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov можно ссылку на код вставить. Но дело в том, что Qt - это кроссплатформенная библиотека, а ассемблер - это под конкретную архитектуру (т.е. не переносимо).

Comment: @alexolut топикстартер что-то говорил про мультиплатформенность? Кстати, если под виндозой использовать MinGW, то прога становится переносимой между виндой и линухом

Comment: @HermannZheboldov [говорил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481559/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment554291_481559). Винда и линукс могут быть на совершенно разных процах быть (arm, x86), ассм тут ну никак не вяжется.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, [void QWidget::grabMouse()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#grabMouse) является решением.

В случае, если требуется бессобытийный опрос мыши, то следует воспользоваться библиотекой SDL, в которой реализована функция [SDL_GetMouseState(int* x, int* y)](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState).

Comment: `grabMouse` перенаправляет все мышиные события определённому виджету. А автору вопроса нужна безсобытийный опрос состояния мыши (скорее всего в цикле).